# Sub menus in css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

Am working on some css menu, am trying to add a sub menu and then another sub menu:

Html:

```
   <div id="menucontainer" class="ui-corner-all ui-widget-header">
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="first">main 1
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li>menu2</li>
            <li>menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>link6
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li>mdfdfenu</li>
            <li>mendfu</li>
            <li>mendfdu</li>
            <li>mendfu</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link7
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li>medfnu</li>
            <li>menudf</li>
            <li>mzxcenu</li>
            <li>medfnu</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link8
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li>menu</li>
            <li>xzcmenu</li>
            <li>menu</li>
            <li>menu</li>
            <li>menu
```

**this extra sub menu**

```
<ul> 
   <li>NEW</li>
    <li>NEW</li>
 </ul>

</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
   #menucontainer {
border: #cccccc 1px solid;
color: #333333;
font-weight: bold;
height: 35px;
width: auto;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
ul#menu {
font-size: 1.1em;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none;
position: relative;
float: right;
z-index: 10;
width: auto;
}
ul#menu li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
border: none;
border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
height: 35px;
}
ul#menu li .first {
border-left: 0 !important;
}
ul#menu li a {
margin: 5px 20px 5px 29px;
padding: 0;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.6em;
color: #0090d4;
 }
 ul#menu li a:hover {
color: #005a8b;
text-decoration: none;
 }
ul#menu li a:active {
color: #cd0a0a;
 }
 ul#menu li .selected a {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu {
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
border: #cccccc 1px solid;
margin: -5px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0;
width: 142px;
display: none;
}
 ul#menu ul.subMenu li {
display: block !important;
width: 140px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none !important;
}
  ul#menu ul.subMenu li:hover {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li a {
padding: 5px !important;
margin: 0 !important;
text-align: left !important;
 }
ul#menu ul.subMenu li#navDeviceSearch {
width: 130px;
height: 50px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
text-align: left;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li#navDeviceSearch label {
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li#navDeviceSearch input {
width: 128px;
color: #cccccc;
font-style: italic;
 }
```

Js: https://jsfiddle.net/zxrd10Lh/1/

For some reason its not letting me get the li showing, even though i have everything, am trying to show SubMenu and NEW from the main menu. i tried getting the right classes from another site, but i dont understand why its not working.

**PS I have fixed the sub menu, but need a fix for the sub sub menu "new"**

Thanks

Comment: Please include **all** relevant code in your question itself, instead of merely linking to jsFiddle.

Comment: Sorry thought it be to long, but iv added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a background color to the 'New' menu so you could see the positoning

```css
#menucontainer {
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 35px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
ul#menu {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
  width: auto;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  height: 35px;
}
ul#menu li .first {
  border-left: 0 !important;
}
ul#menu li a {
  margin: 5px 20px 5px 29px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  color: #0090d4;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: #005a8b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a:active {
  color: #cd0a0a;
}
ul#menu li .selected a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu {
  margin-top: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
  width: 142px;
  display: none;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.subMenu {
  display: block;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li {
  display: block !important;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none !important;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li a {
  padding: 5px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li:hover ul.navDeviceSearch {
  display: block;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu ul.navDeviceSearch {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -20px!important;
  display: none;
}
ul#menu ul.subMenu li ul.navDeviceSearch li {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-style: italic;
  top: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  left: 139px!important;
  position: relative;
}

ul#menu ul.subMenu li ul.navDeviceSearch li:hover {
    background-color:orange;}
```

```html
<div id="menucontainer" class="ui-corner-all ui-widget-header">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="first">main 1
      <ul class="subMenu">
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>main 2
      <ul class="subMenu">
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>main 3
      <ul class="subMenu">
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>main 4
      <ul class="subMenu">
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu</li>
        <li>SubMenu
          <ul class="navDeviceSearch">
            <li>NEW</li>
            <li>NEW</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats working, but when doing this on my computer i sometime realize that the hover doesn't work all the time, when i hover on the menu something it cant open the new submenu, 90% it does but 10% i have hover the menu again, any idea why this can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Remove "display: none;" property form submenu ul.

Comment: I have , but then it displays it all as a block.  my main concern is the submenu while hovering

Comment: oh I understand then leave it "display: none;" as is and write a new css like:

ul#menu li:hover ul.subMenu{display: block;}

after the submenu ul css and I think it's should work.

Comment: yeah that works, but now i just need css for the sub sub menu "NEW" i have updated jsfiddle

Comment: Here's the above fix with the addition of adding a z-index to the submenu so that you can select within it: https://jsfiddle.net/zxrd10Lh/2/

Comment: @Gavin.Paolucci.Kleinow yeh, thats great, but how will i get the sub sub menu "New" to work, at the moment there is no class because am not sure how many ul or li it will have

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/zxrd10Lh/3/ It uses the [> combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to select direct children instead of all children.

Comment: you can simply write css for #menu li ul {css here} you don't have to write css by calling the class of submenu ul.